# Firebase Listener does not identify or resume connection after idle time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My project is to identify whether the client is online or offline. I use the code made available in the Android-Firebase documentation, which uses an EventListener in ".info / connected".

```
// since I can connect from multiple devices, we store each connection instance separately
// any time that connectionsRef's value is null (i.e. has no children) I am offline
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myConnectionsRef = database.getReference("users/joe/connections");

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
final DatabaseReference lastOnlineRef = database.getReference("/users/joe/lastOnline");

final DatabaseReference connectedRef = database.getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      DatabaseReference con = myConnectionsRef.push();

      // when this device disconnects, remove it
      con.onDisconnect().removeValue();

      // when I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
      lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

      // add this device to my connections list
      // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
      con.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled at .info/connected");
  }
});
```

This method correctly identifies when the user terminates or reopens the application or when minor disconnections occur on the internet. However, I did a test turn off the Wifi of the device for a time of 2 minutes, it is identified in the Firebase Database that is not connected, but when I turn on the Wifi, resuming the internet connection, Firebase does not recognize the active connection, appears as if the user still remained inactive.

This code snippet was inserted into the onCreate method of my MainActivity.

Can anyone tell me why this occurs?

---

**EDIT:** **Attachments**

[image: Step #1]

[image: Step #2]

[image: Step #3]

Error log:

> 11-14 10:12:55.272 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.276 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.281 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/Connection: conn_14 - Opening a connection
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.293 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/WebSocket: ws_14 - WebSocket error.
>                                                                                bkx: unknown host: s-usc1c-nss-208.firebaseio.com
>                                                                                    at bku.d(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746448:102)
>                                                                                    at bkv.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746448:4)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: s-usc1c-nss-208.firebaseio.com
>                                                                                    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:174)
>                                                                                    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
>                                                                                    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
>                                                                                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:265)
>                                                                                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:252)
>                                                                                    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:427)
>                                                                                    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:210)
>                                                                                    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:906)
>                                                                                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:192)
>                                                                                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68)
>                                                                                    at bku.d(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746448:94)
>                                                                                    at bkv.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746448:4) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.294 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/WebSocket: ws_14 - closing itself
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.295 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/Connection: conn_14 - Realtime connection failed
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.295 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/Connection: conn_14 - closing realtime connection
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.295 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.296 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.297 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 27403ms
>
> 11-14 10:12:55.304 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/WebSocket: ws_14 - closed
>
> 11-14 10:13:02.947 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Connection interrupted for: connection_idle
>
> 11-14 10:13:02.960 27901-27926/com.example.davi.projetofirebase D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Cancelling existing retry attempt

Comment: When you say that "Firebase does not recognize the active connection", how do you notice that? Is the node in the console for that user not updated? Or is the client not getting new values? Also: if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) for the client, you should be able to see whether the client is reestablishing its connection.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In summary: On turn on Wifi, the node that indicates the established connection is not created in the database (`users/joe/connections`). Additionally, the Listener does not trigger the onDataChange method any more.

I'll try to enable the debug to see what happens.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please see the attachments that I added to the description of the question

Comment: Hmm.... it seems that your client simply is not able to reconnect, which means that the presence system in itself is working correct (`.info/connected` should only be `true` when you're connected). I just tried reproducing this, but on my system the client immediately reconnects when I restore connectivity. What SDK version are you using?

Comment: compileSdkVersion: 26, 
targetSdkVersion: 26, 
Device SDK Version: 24, 
Firebase Version: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4', 
Tool: Android Studio 3.0, 

What is causing the problem may be because I am not using Firebase Auth to authenticate the client?

Comment: I'm also not using Authentication in my tests, so that shouldn't be it.

Comment: Can I send you my project for you to take the test?

Comment: I just upgraded my project to 11.0.4 and still can't reproduce. :-/   If your project is on github I can have a look.

Comment: I created a repository in GitHub so you can better analyze the code:
https://github.com/davimatos/YelooFirebase .

Comment: When I run the code from this repo, it successfully reconnects. You can see the status here: https://teste-e6234.firebaseio.com/terminais/69.json?print=pretty. This makes it highly likely that it's something local to your network connection. Did you try on other connections/devices/networks?

Comment: Very strange. Did you turn off the Wi-Fi, wait 90 seconds, then turn on? I tested it on an Android 7 device and AVD (Turning on airplane mode) and it did not work :(

Comment: Not tested on other networks, I will test and post the result.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I reported the problem to Firebase support, and they acknowledged the bug. They are already analyzing and correcting with the team. Thank you for your help and your availability! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted the support team Firebase, they informed me a solution that apparently solved my problem:

Apparently the listener for .info / connected stops listening if there is no active action or listener for the database. I added another helper listener to any one node in my database, and it worked!

```
DatabaseReference myConnectionRef2 = database.getReference("/users/joe/lastOnline");
myConnectionRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
            System.out.println("FIREBASE: Aux connected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FIREBASE: Aux not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Every time I lose the network connection, the two listeners try to resume communication until the network is reconnected.

Thanks to everyone who helped me solve this problem.

Comment: For those who aren't clear on this answer. You have to make **2 separate connections**. Create 1 ref that connects to `.info/connected` and then create an entirely separate ref that connects to somewhere in your database such as `/users/`. You add a `ValueEventListener` for each ref separately. Basically they are both listening for the connection state. It seems that `.info/connected` needs know that there is a 2nd ref to keep it (.info/connected) from disconnecting after 60secs of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

As Franks says, if you enable `debug logging` for the client, will be able for sure to see the state of the connection, whether the client is reestablishing its connection or not.

```
public synchronized void setLogLevel (Logger.Level logLevel)
```

> By default, this is set to [INFO](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level.html#INFO). This includes any internal errors ([ERROR](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level#ERROR)) and any security debug messages ([INFO](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level.html#INFO)) that the client receives. Set to [DEBUG](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level#DEBUG) to turn on the diagnostic logging, and [NONE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level#NONE) to disable all logging.

Comment: The connection state of a client should not be persisted to disk. I don't think disk persistence is related to the `.info/connected` node that Davi is asking about.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! You are right. Just updated my answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for help. I'll try to enable the debug to see what happens.

Comment: Yeap, give it a try. Also keep me posted.

Comment: @AlexMamo Please see the attachments that I added to the description of the question.

Comment: Take a look a this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) for a better undestanding.

Comment: I tested the same code in Javascript, and it worked on all the tests I did. Apparently the problem only occurs on Android. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe @FrankvanPuffelen has another idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AlexMamo