# Firebase realtime database .info/connected False when it should be True

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android service that calls this at `onCreate`:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
database.getReference(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: " + snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
});
```

I've noticed that when I do some amount of toggling wifi and cellular data, I eventually see a "connected: false" message and no "connected: true" message. Along with the Firebase realtime database, I'm also running Firestore in the service, and Firestore is properly connecting at this point.

I then trigger the Android service to run this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("random/data").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           // This method is called once with the initial value and again
           // whenever data at this location is updated.
           boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
           Log.d(TAG, "random data: " + connected);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
           // Failed to read value
           Log.w(TAG, "cancelled system/online.", error.toException());
        }
});
```

And now, I get a successful read *and* "connected: true" is printed.

What's happening? Why do I need to read from firebase for `.info/connected` to trigger?

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your code where you are reading something from Firestore, you are only reading data from Firebase realtime database, which is a total different product.

Comment: Oops, fixed the text, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do I need to read from firebase for `.info/connected` to trigger?

The answer stays in the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities):

> Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the Firebase Realtime Database client's connection state changes.
>
> `/.info/connected` is a boolean value which is **not** synchronized between realtime database clients because the value is dependent on the state of the client. In other words, if one client reads `/.info/connected` as false, this is no guarantee that a separate client will also read false.
>
> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the `goOffline` method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

So on Android, you can also take advantage of the connection state management. So once you implement the above solution, you'll see that the SDK manages this dynamically in a way that the connections disconnect automatically if there are no listeners attached and if no write operations using `setValue()` are made in the app in last 60 seconds, but the presence of a `ValueEventListners` will override this and will ensure continuous connectivity with the database. You can also take a look at answers within this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265074/firebase-listener-does-not-identify-or-resume-connection-after-idle-time).

There is also another [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) that I recommend you to read for a better understanding.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Woah, that might be the answer! So you're saying that if I just run the app for 60 seconds, it will go to "connected: false" without me doing anything? I need to check that to confirm that hypothesis.

Comment: Woah, it looks like you are exactly right! If I wait exactly 60 seconds, "connected: false" does indeed get printed. I was listening to firestore listeners, but only when I listen to firebase listeners does this timeout go away. Now `.info/connected` seems very reliable. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @AlexMamo. A bit of an old question here but I have a question for you. If we need to read something from database to trigger ".info/connected", how can we check if the user has internet connection? I would appreciate if you answer my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026589/whats-up-with-firebase-info-connected

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include the server region if it is outside the United States.

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https .... europe-west1...").getReference(".info/connected");
```