# What's up with Firebase ".info/connected"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the answer below, we need to read from the database to be able to trigger ".info/connected" ;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222060/12755203

I am trying to use this ".info/connected" to check if the user has internet connection. Therefore, I first check the boolean value returned from ".info/connected" and if it is true, then I try to read other data. However, it keeps sending me false on my first try even though there is internet access. Therefore, my program decides not to read other data thinking that there is no internet connection.

According to the answer above and my experience, there is no way you can check if the user has internet access by using ".info/connected" unless you read something from database which ironically requires internet access.

Then, what is this ".info/connected" used for? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to check if the user has internet access by using ".info/connected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works best for me now is to get value from ".info/connected", don't care about it and then use `Thread.sleep(1200)` to pass some time. (Let it be more than 1 second) And then, call ".info/connected" to actually see if the user has internet connection. The first call is not likely or supposed to be correct, it is just to trigger it to send the correct value on the second time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very helpful to just query it a single time.  A more helpful implementation would be to add a listener (as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state)) to that location so your code can be updated as soon as a change in connectivity is known.  Your app can respond to these changes as needed.

You should also be aware that changes in connectivity can take some time to reflect in .info/connected.  Slow or flakey connection will not necessarily cause changes to .info/connected.  If the user's device loses connectivity for some reason, .info/connected will not necessarily reflect that immediately.  It will take some time for socket operations to time out before Android declares that the connection is definitely gone.  There is really no way around this fact - it's not always possible to tell a lost connection from one that's simply laggy.

.info/connected is good for reflecting the user the general state of the connection, but since it can be delayed, it shouldn't be considered an indicator that the next query will definitely complete immediately due to connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When there are changes in connectivity, it is tolerable that instant changes don't happen. However, sending value false in the scenario where the app is launched and the phone has been having stable internet connection but no request to the database has been made, makes ".info/connected" useless for checking internet connection.

Comment: It's not useless if you add a listener and respond to changes that occur.  It takes time to establish the socket.  There is nothing instant about that.

Answer (score 2):

The `.info/connected` node in the Firebase Realtime Database client indicates whether the client is connected to the Firebase Realtime Database servers. This requires much more than just having an internet connection, which is also the reason the `.info/connected` value is `false` for some time after the app starts, even if your device already has an internet connection.

Comment: So, we shouldn't rely on ".info/connected" when deciding if the user has internet connection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I called `firebase.database().goOnline()` some time before I started listening on `.info/connected`.
Depending on your application, you may want to do it when your application starts.