# Firebase Observer Memory Leak -Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, memory-leaks

I need to make sure the user is connected to Firebase so I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47598180/4833705) to create the listeners in a Base class that I can use for any firebase related activities. The answer works because I don't have to worry about `.info/connected` timing out after 60 secs of inactivity. But when I ran the below code through LeakCanary, the Firebase code in the Base class is  causing a memory leak in PostActivity. I notice when I put break points on the print statements in `removeWifiListeners()`, they don't get hit.

Base class that creates and removes `ValueEventListener`

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var isConnectedListener: ((isReachable: Boolean)->Unit)?= null

    private val connectedRef: DatabaseReference = Firebase.database.getReference(".info/connected")
    private val myConnectionRef: DatabaseReference = Firebase.database.getReference("/users")

    fun startWifiListeners() {
        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean::class.java) ?: false
                if (connected) {
                    isConnectedListener?.invoke(true)
                } else {
                    isConnectedListener?.invoke(false)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                isConnectedListener?.invoke(false)
            }
        })

        myConnectionRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.value == null) {
                    println("FIREBASE: Aux connected")
                } else {
                    println("FIREBASE: Aux not connected")
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled")
            }
        })
    }

    fun removeWifiListeners() {

        connectedRef.removeEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                println("connectedRef - disconnected")
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                println("connectedRef - disconnected - Error: ${error.message}")
            }
        })

        myConnectionRef.removeEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                println("myConnectionRef - disconnected")
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                println("myConnectionRef - disconnected - Error: ${error.message}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Leaking class that inherits Base class, calls the above functions, and when is popped of the stack, leaks

```
class PostActivity: BaseActivity() {

    private var isConnected = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        isConnectedListener = { isReachable ->
            isConnected = isReachable
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        startWifiListeners() // If I comment this out, LeakCanary doesn't find anything, so it's definitely the Firebase code
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        removeWifiListeners()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        removeWifiListeners()
    }
}
```